# Sentencia SQL para encontrar un ultimo registro por cliente mediante fecha

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando crear una sentencia que me devuelva un campo a partir de una fecha, pero bajo cierta condición.

Ante todo tengo una tabla con varios campos, entre los cuales me interesan los de la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que me devuelva el ultimo registro introducido por fecha.

Ej: Criterio de búsqueda **2018-02-28** me devuelve el ID CLIENTE **4**.

Ej: Criterio de búsqueda **2018-03-04** me devuelve el ID CLIENTE **2**.

Ej: Criterio de búsqueda **2018-02-15** no me devuelve nada.

Hasta el momento tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
SELECT `cliente` FROM `Historial` WHERE `fecha` LIKE '%$busqueda%' GROUP BY `cliente` ORDER BY `fecha` DESC
```

Donde $busqueda viene a ser la fecha.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes realizar un max del ID CLIENTE de la siguiente forma:

```
select 
  max(A.Fecha),A.idcliente
from 
  historial A 
      inner join (SELECT 
                    MAX(id) as id,idcliente 
                FROM 
                    Historial 

                GROUP BY 
                    idcliente ) B on b.idcliente = a.idcliente
group by 
    A.idcliente
having 
  max(A.Fecha)= '2018-02-26'
```

Recorda que si queres agregar mas campos al select de tu consulta tambien deberas agregarlos al group by como por ejemplo el nombre del cliente.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/884cd/17

Comment: Buenas, gracias por contestar tan rapido. No me sirve pues esto me devuelve el id de cliente mas alto. La idea es que puede coincidir la fecha para mas de un cliente pero solo me recoge dicho id si la fecha coincide con el ultimo registro para ese cliente.

Comment: Vos necesitas el ultimo registro ingresado para cada cliente dada una fecha?

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que necesito.

Comment: Ah ok entonces te pregunto lo siguiente, como identificas 2 registros distintos para un cliente dada una fecha, porque en la estructura que pasas solo veo id y fecha, decime si no se entiende lo que te pregunto.

Comment: Utilizo otro campo a modo de id primary con autoincrement de modo que puedo repetir tantos ids de cliente como quiera. Supongo que te refieres a eso.

Comment: Claro te lo pregunto porque si vos tenes 2 registros con idcliente 1 y fecha 2018-02-28 por ejemplo, como sabes cual es el utlimo si los 2 tienen la misma fecha, ¿hay otro campo que aparte del idcliente sea idregistro o algo por el estilo? y como se llama ese campo si existe?

Comment: Asi es, se llama ID

Comment: podrias agregar un campo por ejemplo "created_at" que guarde la fecha y hora de creación del registro y luego en la query que te dieron como respuesta, cambiar la funcion max a MAX(created_at)

Comment: con la respuesta que acabas de dar con el campo ID, si usas la query de la respuesta cambiando la funcion "max" a MAX(id), deberia funcionar y agregando todos los campos que necesites sino solo te va a devolver el id XD

Comment: TE modifique la respuesta ya que con esa info que me pasaste ahora si entendi, probalo y avisa.

Comment: Gracias por el seguimiento pero sigue sin ser correcto. Me recupera ids de cliente cuyo ultimo registro es posterior a la fecha que he buscado.

Comment: No puede ser, estas pasando bien la fecha del filtro? Te agregue un ejemplo en el sqlfiddle para que lo veas que funciona.

Comment: Acabo de ver el fiddle. Si cambias la fecha de la primera linea a 2018-02-26 me debería devolver solamente el id cliente 1, el id cliente 4 tiene esta fecha pero no es su ultimo registro. Agrego el fiddle actualizado http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/884cd/1/0

Comment: Recién entendí que querías filtrar los cuales no son su ultimo registro ahí te modifique la consulta y el sqlfiddle.

Comment: Parecía que si funcionaba pero aun falta algo por cuadrar. Voy a preparar algunos datos probando tu sentencia y te aviso.

Comment: Dale avisa cualquier cosa.

Comment: He revisado el código y lo he testado con datos reales. Todo funciona bien. Muchas gracias por la ayuda Hector, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Sabiendo que tienes un campo adicional que es `ID` y es `AUTOINCREMENT`, podrias usar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT cliente, fecha FROM historial WHERE fecha ='$busqueda'
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Eso me devolveria el id mas alto, lo que quiero yo es que me devuelva el id mas alto por cada id cliente.